# sql query and dropdownlist

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, asp.net, html.dropdownlistfor

I have a drop down list which has the values of column's table.

and I have the following statement in c#:

```
string raf = string.Format("select Id from Customer WHERE email="dropdownlist1");
```

how can assign the value of the drop down list to email ?

Comment: make sure you use parameters

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `.SelectedValue` property to fetch the value of dropdown:-

```
string raf = string.Format("select Id from Customer WHERE email={0}",
                                  dropdownlist1.SelectedValue);
```

For fetching dropdown text:-

```
string raf = string.Format("select Id from Customer WHERE email={0}",
                                    dropdownlist1.SelectedItem.Text);
```

Also, Note you need a place holder like `{0}`, when using `String.Format`.

Though as per your query, you are mostly hitting a database, so beware of [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection), use parameterized query like this:-

```
  string raf = select Id from Customer WHERE email=@DropdownText;
  SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(raf,conn);
  cmd.Parameters.Add("@DropdownText",SqlDbType.NVarchar,20).Value =
                                      dropdownlist1.SelectedItem.Text;
```

Comment: The above solution is open to SQL injection attack. The proper way is to use sql parameter

Comment: @TienDinh - Yeah OP didn't mentioned that he is going to hit DB but as per his statement I should have considered that and BTW was updating that only when you commented. Thanks.

Comment: how can i display the value of the selected Id into a label ?

Comment: @RefaatKh - Simple: `LabelId.Text = dropdownlist1.SelectedItem.Text;`

Comment: no, i mean the "id" where the value = dropdownlist.

Comment: @RefaatKh - I am not getting what you mean. Id of what? Can't answer without any code.

Comment: @RefaatKh - No you should not do that. Edit your this question  if it is similar.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27874566/sql-and-c-sharp-error please go there

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
string raf = string.Format("select Id from Customer 
WHERE email='{0}'",dropdownlist1.SelectedValue));
```

`{0}` Means Your are fetching First Argument of `string.Format` method

Beware of `SQL Injection` Always Use [SQL Parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: You don't need `ToString()`, `SelectedValue` property returns `String`.