# getting values from sql reader c#

Tags: c#, sql

I have the following code:

```
SqlConnection c = new SqlConnection("Data Source=localhost\\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=BookStoreDataBase1;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False;");
c.Open();

string raf = string.Format("Select Id from Customer WHERE email='{0}'", DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text);
SqlCommand comm2 = new SqlCommand(raf, c);
SqlDataReader r = comm2.ExecuteReader();
```

The object `r` now has the value of the query which is a row contains that the Id where email equals to random value from drop down list.

what I want is to get the exact value of that "Id" and assign it to label. please help me.

Comment: r.Read();   lbl.Text = r.GetInt32(0).ToString();

Comment: I wonder which tutorial stops at that point without showing also the part where you retrieve the results of your query.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27873913/sql-query-and-dropdownlist

Comment: Tagging is terrible. Question is not related to asp.net, mysql..and try-catch(?!)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of all your query is open to `SQL Injection attack` so change it like this:-

```
string raf = "Select Id from Customer WHERE email= @Email";
SqlCommand comm2 = new SqlCommand(raf, c);
cmoo2.Parameters.Add("@Email",SqlDbType.NVarchar,20).Value =  
                                           DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text;
```

You are fetching just one value so it can be done use `ExecuteScalar` like this:-

```
labelid.Text= cmoo2.ExecuteScalar.ToString();
```

But If you want to use `SqlDataReader` object then it will return the value when you call the `Read` method:-

```
using(SqlDataReader reader= cmoo2.ExecuteReader())
{
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        labelid.Text= reader["Id"].ToString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are lot of examples already in stack overflow regarding this topic you can refer any of that answers or try this

```
using(SqlDataReader r= cmd.ExecuteReader())
{
    while (r.Read())
    {
        var myString = r.GetString(0); //The 0 stands for "the 0'th column", so the first column of the result.
        labelid.Text=myString;
    }
}
```